# How to find the version of an azure Function App?

Tags: python, azure-functions, cloud

I want to check what is the python version that my Azure Function App is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using azure CLI - **az**

1. Install **az** - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/.
2. Use `az login` to login to your azure account
3. Then execute `az functionapp show -g [resource_name] --name [Function APP name] | grep linuxFxVersion`

Helpful: You might need to install [azure-functions-core-tools](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools.)

Answer (score 3):

When looking a the Function App in the Azure Portal, you can also head to the `Configuration` tab under `Settings` on the left:

[image]

And then head to the `General settings` tab at the top to see `Stack Settings`:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the answer but  I’m this case I wanted to check the azure function stack version and not the python version. Good to know the python version anyways :)

Comment: I came to this question after googling "How to find the python version of an Azure Function", so hopefully this answer will help someone else doing the same thing