# How to check my current azure function version?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

Here I can see the latest azure function version is 4.x -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=v4&pivots=programming-language-csharp

I also would like to use version 4.x of the azure function, but i am not able to use it.

I checked it over here, function app > configurations. I can only see `~3` in run time version not `~4`

[image]

Also, the version specified in `host.json` is `2.x`.

```
// host.json
{
    "version": "2.0",
}
```

### Setup

- Azure function premium plan
- Deployed on docker - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=in-process%2Cbash%2Cazure-cli&pivots=programming-language-javascript

I tried setting the version in `host.json` to 4.0 but having the following issue in vscode.

[image]

Which one is the actual azure function version that is being used in my case, and how to upgrade it to version 4.x?

Reference

[How to find the version of an azure Function App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71936193/how-to-find-the-version-of-an-azure-function-app)

Comment: Did you see this by chance? ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4 ... I believe this to be the key component ... `<AzureFunctionsVersion>` in your project file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to check my current azure function version?

In portal you can check as below:

[image]

Alternatively, I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4?tabs=net6-in-proc,azure-cli,windows&pivots=programming-language-csharp):

Below is my script which got my function apps run time version which i executed in Azure PowerShell:

```
$Subscription = 'Azure cc'        
Set-AzContext -Subscription $Subscription | Out-Null 
$FunctionApps = Get-AzFunctionApp
$res =@{}
foreach ($x in $FunctionApps)
{
$res= $x.Name + $x.ApplicationSettings.FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION
$res 
}
```

[image]

[image]

This way you can get to know which version you are using.

Comment: Thanks, as you said it can be specified in the application configuration. What’s the role of the version in `host.json`? Isn’t it function run time version?